# On the insertion dynamic column of mariaDB

Tags: java, mariadb, mariadb-connect-engine

```
set @v1 = "'city', 'ITY', 'age', '20'";
select @v1;
insert into test values (11, 'hidy', column_create(@v1));
```

MariaDB does not support this variable in the form of an insert，and

```
client Error at))
MariaDB :10.1.19
client :heidi 9.4.0.5130 
OS: Windows 10
```

How can I insert in variable form? Because I want to use JDBC in my JAVA to pass parameters

Comment: Need To Improve Formatting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use prepared statements for INSERT.

```
MariaDB [test]> set @v1 = "'city', 'ITY', 'age', '20'";
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

MariaDB [test]> set @q = concat("insert into test values(11, 'hidy', column_create(",@v1,"))");
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [test]> select @q;
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| @q                                                                             |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| insert into test values(11, 'hidy', column_create('city', 'ITY', 'age', '20')) |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [test]> prepare stmt from @q;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Statement prepared

MariaDB [test]> execute stmt;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.26 sec)

MariaDB [test]> select column_get(b,'city' as char(8)) from test;
+---------------------------------+
| column_get(b,'city' as char(8)) |
+---------------------------------+
| ITY                             |
+---------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: thanks。This gets the JSON value is more difficult than MYSQL